# ORM for SQL Server on Node.js

Tags: sql-server, node.js, orm

I'm on the look for an ORM mapper for SQL Server on Node.js. Long story short, we have a SQL Server running and now we want to use node.js to build web services pulling data from the database.

Do you know any ORM that supports SQL Server on Node.js?

I know that there is this [tedious](https://github.com/pekim/tedious) which can help connect to SQL Server but it does not have ORM.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the rant but this is pretty much the only reason why I'm not using node.js. It would be nice to not have to code java or python to be simply cross-platform... like python though and am using sqlalchemy and alembic to finally not have to touch the db anymore.

Comment: @Asken Yep, that's the thing. There are many ORM on node but they only support one or two database. There should be a universal solution which you can connect to any database. I found this library https://github.com/1602/jugglingdb/ which is potentially going that way. But they haven't got SQL Server on the list yet :(

Comment: is there any progress with ORM for MSSQL?

Comment: @EugeneKrevenets - I've zero experience with it, but I've noticed that LoopBack has support for SQL Server (npm install loopback-connector-mssql).  See http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/SQL+Server+connector - if anyone has experience with it as an ORM (especially as a standalone use, outside of LoopBack), that'd be great to hear about. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SQL Server so far hasn't gotten a great deal of support yet in the Node.js community. And, since most of the Node.js ecosystem is community-driven, your options will likely be rather limited.

That's not to say there aren't plans to add support for it; just that not many have achieved it yet. Example: The author of [`sequelize`](https://npmjs.org/package/sequelize) has stated [intent to add support eventually](https://twitter.com/sdepold/status/264442316725551104).

For now, if it's enough to get plain `Object`s with columns as keys, Microsoft's own [`msnodesql`](https://npmjs.org/package/msnodesql) can be a good option with [its `query()` method](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/node-sqlserver/blob/master/test/query.js#L35-L45):

```
sql.query(conn_str, "SELECT 1 as X, 'ABC', 0x0123456789abcdef ", function (err, results) {

    assert.ifError(err);

    var buffer = new Buffer('0123456789abcdef', 'hex');
    var expected = [{ 'X': 1, 'Column1': 'ABC', 'Column2': buffer}];

    assert.deepEqual(results, expected, "Results don't match");

    done();
});
```

Comment: sequelize has now support for mssql and I think since this is the accepted answer, you should update

Comment: This answer is not acceptable at this point in time. Sequelize has support to multiple RDBMS vendors including MS Sql Server

Answer (score 23):

According to [sequelize](/questions/tagged/sequelize)'s [documentation](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), [orm](/questions/tagged/orm) support for [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) is available in version 2.0 (released on [Feb. 10, 2015](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/releases/tag/v2.0.0), previously added on [Dec. 22, 2014](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/changelog.md#200-rc4)'s release candidate).

Comment: sequelize's orm support was added much later than the question was asked, but this is the best answer

Comment: I just tested it and it doesn't support the SQL Server's DATETIME type, if you have tables using this type your queries will fail. An alternative would be https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest taking a look at [Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/). We just [announced](https://www.prisma.io/blog/prisma-sql-server-support-preview-a4anl2gd8d3a) preview support for SQL Server.

It's an ORM that puts the emphasis on type-safety and developer experience. Unlike traditional ORMs that typically map tables to classes, Prisma maps queries to types (in TypeScript) and returns plain objects from queries.

To get started with Prisma and SQL Server check out this [example](https://github.com/prisma/prisma-examples/tree/latest/databases/sql-server) and [start from scratch guide in the docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/tools-and-interfaces/preview-features/sql-server/sql-server-start-from-scratch-typescript).

Answer (score 2):

I like [Node-odbc](https://github.com/w1nk/node-odbc),  I think some kind of ODBC abstraction is probably best all RDBMS' with NodeJS

Comment: agreed. the whole point of node vs say .NET is to stay agnostic. do all your db stuff specific to that database engine on the database and don't let it infect your app server

Answer (score 1):

I am using [Bookshelf](http://bookshelfjs.org) ORM, it has built-in support for MS SQL Server via its dependency on [Knex.js](http://knexjs.org), though it's not explicitly listed on the Bookshelf website.

Specify `client: 'mssql'` on initialization of Bookshelf.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [mssql-orm](https://www.npmjs.org/package/mssql-orm). It supports writing large object graphs to SQL Server, but has a very lightweight API:

```
var person = db.model({table: 'people'});

var bob = person({
  name: 'bob'
});

bob.save();
```

Comment: Only supports write-only, they need read specifically at least.